After sending around 30 requests to NCBI the subsequent requests take a very long time to be retrieved
I'm trying to get info about some genes which are their DNA and mRNA length and I'm doing this by getting around 500 genes IDs and then sending a request to ncbi to get info about the genes DNA length and then sending another request to get info regarding its mRNA and the code is doing this perfectly fine. The problem is after sending around 30 requests the next requests take a very long time to be retrieved almost 20 mins per request. And nothing mentioned in their documentation about a limit or something the only thing that is mentioned is the rate limit is 3 requests per second. So is there a way to get these info for like a 1000 genes in the same speed as I get the very first 30 ones?
Here is my code:
from Bio import Entrez, SeqIO

Entrez.email = "MY_EMAIl"
Entrez.api_key = "My_API"
# Search for Homo sapiens genes
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term='Homo     sapiens[Organism]', rettype="gb", retmax=100)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()

nucleotide_ids = record["IdList"]  # List of Nucleotide IDs
print(f"Found {len(nucleotide_ids)} IDs for term 'Homo sapiens[Organism]'")

# Loop through the list of gene IDs and fetch information
for n in nucleotide_ids:
   # Fetch the GenBank record for each gene ID
   handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=n, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
   record = SeqIO.read(handle, "genbank")
   handle.close()

   # Get the DNA length directly from the sequence
   dna_length = len(record.seq)
   print(n)
   print(f"DNA Length: {dna_length} bp")

   # Extract chromosome number from the source feature (if available)
   chromosome = "Not available"
   for feature in record.features:
       if feature.type == "source" and "chromosome" in feature.qualifiers:
           chromosome = feature.qualifiers["chromosome"][0]
            break  # Exit after finding the chromosome

   print(f"Chromosome: {chromosome}")

   # Initialize variable for mRNA transcript ID
   mrna_transcript_id = None

   # Loop through features to find the first mRNA feature with a transcript ID
   for feature in record.features:
       if feature.type == "mRNA" and "transcript_id" in feature.qualifiers:
           # Extract the transcript ID
           mrna_transcript_id = feature.qualifiers["transcript_id"][0]
           print("mRNA transcript ID:", mrna_transcript_id)
           break  # Stop after finding the first mRNA transcript ID

   # Check if mRNA transcript ID was found
   if mrna_transcript_id:
       # Fetch only the base part of the transcript ID, removing any version number
       transcript_id = mrna_transcript_id.split(".")[0]

       # Fetch the mRNA sequence data using the transcript ID to get its length
       handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=transcript_id, rettype="gb", retmode="text")
       mrna_record = SeqIO.read(handle, "genbank")
       handle.close()

       # Calculate and print the mRNA length
       mrna_length = len(mrna_record.seq)
       print(f"mRNA Length: {mrna_length} bp")
   else:
       print("No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.")
    

And here is the output till where it always starts to take a very long time:
> Found 100 IDs for term 'Homo sapiens[Organism]'
2844834341
DNA Length: 3046 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831162
DNA Length: 317 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831161
DNA Length: 314 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831160
DNA Length: 678 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831159
DNA Length: 680 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831158
DNA Length: 493 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831157
DNA Length: 492 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831156
DNA Length: 331 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831155
DNA Length: 329 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831154
DNA Length: 777 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831153
DNA Length: 777 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831152
DNA Length: 420 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831151
DNA Length: 441 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831150
DNA Length: 633 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831149
DNA Length: 634 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
DNA Length: 633 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831149
DNA Length: 634 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831149
DNA Length: 634 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844831149
DNA Length: 634 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
DNA Length: 634 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
2844741236
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
DNA Length: 800 bp
Chromosome: Not available
Chromosome: Not available
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2302519926
DNA Length: 31849 bp
Chromosome: 8
mRNA transcript ID: NM_078480.3
mRNA Length: 1868 bp
2302519820
DNA Length: 10320 bp
Chromosome: 17
mRNA transcript ID: NM_172089.4
mRNA Length: 1857 bp
1546674230
DNA Length: 297579 bp
Chromosome: 21
mRNA transcript ID: NM_000484.4
mRNA Length: 3583 bp
1519312921
DNA Length: 4473 bp
Chromosome: 7
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
1243938659
DNA Length: 14518 bp
Chromosome: 8
mRNA transcript ID: NM_002467.6
mRNA Length: 3721 bp
1190332594
DNA Length: 60422 bp
Chromosome: 15
mRNA transcript ID: NM_001080541.3
mRNA Length: 11419 bp
1122782504
DNA Length: 67646 bp
Chromosome: 3
mRNA transcript ID: NM_001904.4
mRNA Length: 3661 bp
1050193339
DNA Length: 64762 bp
Chromosome: 2
mRNA transcript ID: NM_021027.3
mRNA Length: 2371 bp
432134280
DNA Length: 13042 bp
Chromosome: 2
mRNA transcript ID: NM_022152.6
mRNA Length: 2292 bp
347800663
DNA Length: 32232 bp
Chromosome: 11
mRNA transcript ID: NM_001369449.1
mRNA Length: 1806 bp
345525407
DNA Length: 27064 bp
345525407
DNA Length: 27064 bp
DNA Length: 27064 bp
Chromosome: 15
mRNA transcript ID: NM_014994.3
mRNA Length: 7182 bp
224809401
DNA Length: 30237 bp
Chromosome: 12
mRNA transcript ID: NM_001982.3
mRNA Length: 5615 bp
2850708328
DNA Length: 2457175 bp
Chromosome: contig-37
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.
2850708327
DNA Length: 2784344 bp
Chromosome: contig-36
No mRNA transcript ID found in the record.

